# Rails 5 Windows installation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

currently trying to install rails on windows. Since I have already tried to find solutions and to fasten this up, here's a list:

- Using Windows 8 64bit
- DevKit (64bit) IS installed (On C: root)
- I'm admin and using CMD with admin rights
- Ruby Version: 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x68-mingw32]
- Gems Version: 2.6.7

CMD Log: http://pastebin.com/cETfTDtr
On pastebin since somehow it doesn't want to format it properly.

mkmf.log File:

```
have_header: checking for unistd.h... -------------------- yes

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -I"C:/Program Files/Ruby/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32" -I"C:/Program Files/Ruby/include/ruby-2.3.0"/ruby/backward -I"C:/Program Files/Ruby/include/ruby-2.3.0" -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat conftest.c  -L. -L"C:/Program Files/Ruby/lib" -L.      -lx64-msvcrt-ruby230  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
6: {
7:   return 0;
8: }
/* end */

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -E -I"C:/Program Files/Ruby/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32" -I"C:/Program Files/Ruby/include/ruby-2.3.0"/ruby/backward -I"C:/Program Files/Ruby/include/ruby-2.3.0" -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat  conftest.c -o conftest.i"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: #include <unistd.h>
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... -------------------- no

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -I"C:/Program Files/Ruby/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32" -I"C:/Program Files/Ruby/include/ruby-2.3.0"/ruby/backward -I"C:/Program Files/Ruby/include/ruby-2.3.0" -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat conftest.c  -L. -L"C:/Program Files/Ruby/lib" -L.      -lx64-msvcrt-ruby230  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:16:57: error: 'rb_thread_blocking_region' undeclared (first use in this function)
conftest.c:16:57: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))rb_thread_blocking_region; return !p; }
/* end */

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -I"C:/Program Files/Ruby/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32" -I"C:/Program Files/Ruby/include/ruby-2.3.0"/ruby/backward -I"C:/Program Files/Ruby/include/ruby-2.3.0" -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat conftest.c  -L. -L"C:/Program Files/Ruby/lib" -L.      -lx64-msvcrt-ruby230  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
C:\Users\Dominik\AppData\Local\Temp\ccdMIqPq.o: In function `t':
C:\Program Files\Ruby\lib\ruby\gems\2.3.0\gems\nio4r-1.2.1\ext\nio4r/conftest.c:17: undefined reference to `rb_thread_blocking_region'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: extern void rb_thread_blocking_region();
17: int t(void) { rb_thread_blocking_region(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl()... -------------------- yes

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -I"C:/Program Files/Ruby/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32" -I"C:/Program Files/Ruby/include/ruby-2.3.0"/ruby/backward -I"C:/Program Files/Ruby/include/ruby-2.3.0" -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat conftest.c  -L. -L"C:/Program Files/Ruby/lib" -L.      -lx64-msvcrt-ruby230  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:16:57: error: 'rb_thread_call_without_gvl' undeclared (first use in this function)
conftest.c:16:57: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))rb_thread_call_without_gvl; return !p; }
/* end */

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -I"C:/Program Files/Ruby/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32" -I"C:/Program Files/Ruby/include/ruby-2.3.0"/ruby/backward -I"C:/Program Files/Ruby/include/ruby-2.3.0" -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat conftest.c  -L. -L"C:/Program Files/Ruby/lib" -L.      -lx64-msvcrt-ruby230  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: extern void rb_thread_call_without_gvl();
17: int t(void) { rb_thread_call_without_gvl(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_header: checking for sys/select.h... -------------------- no

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -E -I"C:/Program Files/Ruby/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32" -I"C:/Program Files/Ruby/include/ruby-2.3.0"/ruby/backward -I"C:/Program Files/Ruby/include/ruby-2.3.0" -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat  conftest.c -o conftest.i"
conftest.c:5:24: fatal error: sys/select.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: #include <sys/select.h>
/* end */

--------------------

have_header: checking for poll.h... -------------------- no

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -E -I"C:/Program Files/Ruby/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32" -I"C:/Program Files/Ruby/include/ruby-2.3.0"/ruby/backward -I"C:/Program Files/Ruby/include/ruby-2.3.0" -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat  conftest.c -o conftest.i"
conftest.c:5:18: fatal error: poll.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: #include <poll.h>
/* end */

--------------------

have_header: checking for sys/epoll.h... -------------------- no

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -E -I"C:/Program Files/Ruby/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32" -I"C:/Program Files/Ruby/include/ruby-2.3.0"/ruby/backward -I"C:/Program Files/Ruby/include/ruby-2.3.0" -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat  conftest.c -o conftest.i"
conftest.c:5:23: fatal error: sys/epoll.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: #include <sys/epoll.h>
/* end */

--------------------

have_header: checking for sys/event.h... -------------------- no

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -E -I"C:/Program Files/Ruby/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32" -I"C:/Program Files/Ruby/include/ruby-2.3.0"/ruby/backward -I"C:/Program Files/Ruby/include/ruby-2.3.0" -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat  conftest.c -o conftest.i"
conftest.c:5:23: fatal error: sys/event.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: #include <sys/event.h>
/* end */

--------------------

have_header: checking for port.h... -------------------- no

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -E -I"C:/Program Files/Ruby/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32" -I"C:/Program Files/Ruby/include/ruby-2.3.0"/ruby/backward -I"C:/Program Files/Ruby/include/ruby-2.3.0" -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat  conftest.c -o conftest.i"
conftest.c:5:18: fatal error: port.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: #include <port.h>
/* end */

--------------------

have_header: checking for sys/resource.h... -------------------- no

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -E -I"C:/Program Files/Ruby/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32" -I"C:/Program Files/Ruby/include/ruby-2.3.0"/ruby/backward -I"C:/Program Files/Ruby/include/ruby-2.3.0" -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat  conftest.c -o conftest.i"
conftest.c:5:26: fatal error: sys/resource.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: #include <sys/resource.h>
/* end */

--------------------
```